# Cleaning pipe after second input

Tags: c, char, pipe

I'm new here and I'm beginner in C programming. I have a problem with using pipes to copy a one file to another. My buffer size is 10. When i copy from my file in.txt to out.txt there's always a "p" left on the end of char table. It's just because my last input contains only 9 characters, and the tenth char is from earlier input.
"reader: msg88=as nulla p
reader: msg89=ariatur? p
"

What should I do to clean my char table? I don't want the last "p" on the msg89. I need it to be the same files, but the in.txt doesn't contain the "p" on the end and the out.txt contains. When I use md5sum it's not the same:

```
197ee73779d545f0d3dc7981131736c0  in.txt
ed36f720a1ffc7e82983545d6305edc3  out.txt
```

Code:

```
filefd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0);
for(int i = 0; read(filefd, message, 10) > 0; i++)
{
    printf("writer: msg%d=%s\n", i+1, message);
    fflush(stdout);
    write(fd[1], message, 10);
    usleep(100000);
}


filefd = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
for(int i = 0; read(fd[0], message, 10) > 0; i++)
{
    printf("reader: msg%d=%s\n", i+1, message);
    fflush(stdout);
    write(filefd, message, 10);
    usleep(120000);
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant portion of your code.

Comment: I added it already. The first one is a part of function "producer", the second one is part of function "consumer"

Answer (score 0):

`read` returns the number of bytes read, so you should be able to do something like:

```
ssize_t bytesread;
for (int i = 0; (bytesread = read(fd[0], message, 10)) > 0; i++)
{
  ...
  write(filefd, message, bytesread);
  ...
}
```

The idea is to check the number of bytes read by the call to `read` (I'm storing it in a variable named `bytesread`) and pass that number to the `write` call instead of always passing 10.

I assume you would make a similar change in both pieces of code you posted.